# Disallow following characters in a regex: ~%^*= [{}]|;<>

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm using this regex:

```
^(?!.*&#.*)[a-zA-Z0-9!@_'?., `#$&()-\\\\/:"]*$
```

but it is accepting following characters: `*=+[;<>`
How do I disallow them? I tried adding this `(?!.*(~%^*=+[{}]|;<>))` but it didn't work!

Comment: What language/library/tool are you using?

Comment: I've edited your regexes to display better. Please check them and make sure I didn't introduce any errors.

Comment: It looks like you need to escape a number of the characters in your regex (so much so that I can't really tell what you are literally meaning to do). Also HTML entities like `&amp;` and `&quot;` have no meaning within a character class like that.  I am also confused because you negative lookahead disallows `&amp;` yet you also have it in the regex as an allowable character class.

Comment: @MikeBrant It appears that `&` and `#` are allowed but not the substring `&#`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman My comment was referring to original post before edit which had HTML entities in it in a literal sense.

Comment: I'm using this regex through a config file and assign it in code behind (C#) with a special object in my project. I have to use &amp; and &quot due to regex is in a config file. then, yes, it doesn't allow & and # combination, it shouldn't allow *=+[;<> but it is allowing them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to escape the `-` in there.

```
^(?!.*&#.*)[a-zA-Z0-9!@_'?., `#$&()\\-\\\\/:"]*$
                                   ^^
```

Comment: I believe there were supposed to be only two backslashes in the actual regex.  The extras were there to make them display correctly and should have been removed, just like the HTML entities.  In your regex there should be only *one* backslash before the hyphen and *two* after it.

Comment: 4 extra backslashes were added to make it work cause it wasn't working maybe because I'm using a config file

Comment: Thanks @JohnKugelman. That was my issue! I added this \\- and now it is disallowing the other characters!